# Why do references to formulas in VBA work inside square brackets without application.worksheetfunction?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

Typically, using Excel formulas in VBA requires application.worksheetfunction, eg:

```
application.worksheetfunction.eomonth(today(),1)
application.worksheetfunction.date(2020,1,1)
```

but I am able to run the following without error:

```
[eomonth(today(),1)]
[date(2020,1,1)]   'dateserial() is the VBA version of date() so this would fail without square brackets
```

vlookup however does not work.

I know that the ability to refer to named ranges using square brackets was introduced at some point, but I don't see anything about formulas.

This is in Office 365 ProPlus.

Comment: It is short hand for `Application.Evaluate()`

Comment: And VLOOKUP does work as long as you know the fact that it will use the active sheet as the sheet unless the references state differently.

Comment: And, if you don't want to write sub-optimal code, try to _avoid_ [Application.Evaluate()](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/)